# Windows 7 XP Mode, Resizing triggering lock

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, windows-xp-mode

I'm a developer using Windows 7 XP Mode to get some old 16-bit apps to run.

A hugely annoying hurdle I'm encountering is this:

When I resize my XP windows at all (usually by mistake), it automatically logs me off (or Locks), requiring me to log in.

This causes my build batch file to stop, which is potentially hours of work lost.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP mode uses the latest Windows Virtual PC, which actually uses RDP connecting to the running virtual machine. It does lock you out if you don't have saved credential. So turn the machine off and set up a saved credential from the settings and see if it helps.

However, because this is a saved credential that auto-log you in every time when you resize the window, I am not sure if it helps in your case that you have a build batch file running in the end.

Cheers

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I checked behavior on my PC (Win7 64 bit) and resizing doesn't log me off. So I don't know why it does in your case.

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2005/03/15/396403.aspx) there was an option in Virtual PC to change dynamic resizing behavior but [it seems](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/w7itprovirt/thread/f913febf-73ec-40bb-9f63-77504a812ca3) it's not present in version for Windows 7.

For solution, only thing that comes to mind is to run the virtual maching in full screen. That way you can't accidentally resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting your saved credential then re-entering it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: +1 Awesome. Worked perfectly for me. I didn't have a saved credential, but adding one sorted this problem out for me.